# How does Google detect AMP-HTML

Tags: html, amp-html

At this moment I am in process of re-creating a certain website (not really relevant). What concerns me, however, is AMP version which I want to include.

The thing I don't really understand is how does Google determine AMP version. Let's say I want to have desktop and mobile (amp) version of my site. In the scenario I like, my site schema would look like this

```
http://www.page.com

http://amp.page.com

http://m.page.com (not really needed though)
```

What I don't understand is how Google recognizes what version should be listed in search result. Is it enough if I simply write AMP version as a normal site with AMP standards (like AMP head,  etc) and Google takes care of everything else? Or is there something else "under the hood" that needs to be done for the AMP version to work properly?

Thanks for all replies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damir's answer is correct but let me expand on it.

In addition to the line of code he mentioned you must also include the following line in every amp enabled page.  This line tells search engines that duplicate, non-AMP content exists and where to find it.

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.yoursite.com/non-amp-page.htm">`

99% of the time the content on your AMP page was derived from a non-AMP page.  In that case point at that original page as shown above. 1% of the time (or less) your AMP page is stand alone and a non-AMP version does not exist.  In that case the reference is circular and the page points at itself.  For example `new-amp-page.htm` would contain this line.

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.yoursite.com/new-amp-page.htm">`

This tutorial might help you out.  It goes over AMP setup in detail with diagrams and screenshots.

[How I Used AMP For My Small Business Websit](https://www.cleanpaw.com/amp_small_business.htm)e

Answer (score 1):

Simple Google search revealed the following link: https://searchengineland.com/get-started-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp-240688

> In order for Google (and other technologies supporting the AMP
>   Project) to detect the AMP version of your article, you will need to
>   modify the original version of the article page. The original article
>   page must include the following tag, essentially a canonical tag for
>   AMP pages:
>
> `<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.example.com/blog-post/amp/">`

Comment: Now I see the connection! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance! If the answer was helpful, consider accepting it :)